# How to draw a TH1F in the terminal without opening TBrowser in ROOT?

Tags: root-framework

I have a root directory, when I list the files, I can see there is a file

```
KEY: TH1F  h_met;1
```

I am trying to draw this histogram through a terminal command, and do not want to open TBrowser since it is SUPER slow for me.

Is there a terminal command that will draw this?

I have tried

```
TCanvas *c1 = new TCanvas("c1","c1"); c1->Draw("h_met")
```

but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You should first get the histogram, then plot it. Assuming your file is opened as `f`:

```
TH1F *h1 = (TH1F*)f.Get("h_met");
h1->Draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on `ROOT 6` and assuming your file is called `f.root`, just do

```
root -l f.root -e "h_met->Draw()"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sometimes with the graphics it can become slow,

I recommend to use the option

-b                             Run in batch mode without graphics
So, you can do

```
root -l -q
root [1] TFile f("yourfile.root");
root [2] TH1F *h1 = (TH1F*)f.Get("h_met");
root [3] h1->Draw()
Info in <TCanvas::MakeDefCanvas>:  created default TCanvas with name c1
root [4] c1->SaveAs("save_it_for_open_later.png")
```

As you can see with Draw, the TCanvas c1 is created by default,and with SaveAs, you can save de histogram h1 in png or other format, to open it later with other application.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, you can also actually 'draw' it in terminal, see: https://root-forum.cern.ch/t/tbrowser-alternative-for-non-x11-mode/20754/27